# Array post_meta in wordpress with maquetation

Tags: php, wordpress

somebody knows why can't show post_meta "ojos" with this code? works fine with wp_get_post_terms but i want with post_meta. I suppose is for ($terms) maybe... really thanks!

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_meta($post->ID,'ojos');
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo "<span style='font-size:12px !important;color:#999 !important;font:Arial !important;font-weight:normal !important;'>Color de Ojos: </span><span>";
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo $term->name . "<comma>, </comma>";
         }
              echo "</span>";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'ojos', true);
if($meta != $empty) { echo "<span style='font-size:12px !important;color:#999 !important;font:Arial !important;font-weight:normal !important;'>Color de Ojos: </span><span>" $meta ; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for `get_post_meta()` function instead?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

P.S.
Terms and metadata don't have much in common. They are located in different db tables, saved in a different way and have separate set of functions. And their intent is different as well, e.g. it's not all that healthy to query posts by metadata (it can be done, sure, but taxonomies should work better, especially on large databases).

Comment: sorry, i know that $terms is incorrect. I have a valid code for terms, but i want do the same with metadata. Can you help me please?

Comment: @vektor you need to help *us* to help *you*: add more details to the Question, please, check the guide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Ah, si, formatting your code properly also helps, you see, grand part of the help is your responsibility.

Comment: I only need it some of your maestry, not solution. But i have the code, can you said me if it correct?